# Inserting a Div After Every 5th Wordpress Post?

Tags: wordpress

How could I go about inserting a div after every fifth post on the home page?

Here is my loop:

```
<?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :

                  if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>


                  <?php
                endif;

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;

                the_posts_navigation();

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

                  endif; 


        ?>
```

How could I insert this code in the loop to make the div appear after every 5th post?

```
while( have_posts() ):

    if( 1 == $wp_query->current_post ):
        echo '<div>My div!</div>';
    endif;

endwhile;
```

Answer (score 0):

Before the while, you can declare a variable with value 0, and increment this variable inside the while. Example:

```
    $counter = 0;

    while( have_posts() ):
    // codes
    $counter ++;
    if ($counter >= 5) {
    echo '<div>My div!</div>';
    $counter = 0; // clean to count again
    }
    endwhile;
```

The code will be:

```
<?php
            if ( have_posts() ) :

                  if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                    <header>
                        <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                    </header>


                  <?php
                endif;

$counter = 0;

                /* Start the Loop */
                while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                    /*
                     * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                     * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                     * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                     */
                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

    $counter ++;
    if ($counter >= 5) {
    echo '<div>My div!</div>';
    $counter = 0; // clean to count again
    }

                endwhile;

                the_posts_navigation();

            else :

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

                  endif; 


        ?>
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, inserting my code in your "//code" section, however it seems to break the site. I must be doing it wrong though.

Comment: Try to put only $counter = 0 before the while, and the the $counter ++ with the if before the endwhile. The //codes is just an example that in this place will have some wordpress codes. I will edit my comment to show exactly how it should be applied to your theme.

Comment: Oh, I see! Well, it surely works now! Thank you so much for taking the time to help me bruno! Very much appreciated!